# How to modify a AVAudioPCMBuffer in swift

Tags: swift, avaudiopcmbuffer

does anybody know how to modify the buffer contents of
an AVAudioPCMBuffer object? I want to do the following:

1. load an audio file into an AVAudioPCMBuffer - this works.
2. modify the samples data of the AVAudioPCMBuffer. - here i stuck
3. write the AVAudioPCMBuffer to a file - this also works.

as in the documentation layed out, the AVAudioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData
is unfortunately read-only. Also the itAudio.audioBufferList.memory.mBuffers.mData seems to be read-only. 
the compiler shows: cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only. currently i am using the audiotoolbox, which works fine for my
purposes. nevertheless i would like to ask if anybody knows the (best practice) way for doing this job?
thanks a lot for any help!!!